# OK to drain 2nd vanity sink like drawing? Will this meet code?

Tags: plumbing

Hope you can take a look at the drawing and let me know if its ok to hook up the waste like this. The plan is to remove a section of gal at both locations in red and install a pvc sanitary tee and attach with 1-1/2" Fernco Proflex couplings. The existing sink drain that will be removed is @ 14" center. The 2 new drains will be @ 22" center to get up inside the vanity. Hope this makes sense.
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

You show a trap for the laundry, so you need a trap for both sinks and the shower, if you don't fit them then you could / will end up with smells coming in...

Comment: Sorry. Did't show traps. The existing shower has one and I'll install separate traps inside the new vanity for the sinks. I just wanted to make sure I can add sink #2 to the existing 1-1/2" vent

Answer (score -3):

It may not meet “code” due to the number of fixtures with just an 1-1/2” vent, but I think it will work fine. Also, “code” may require the vent to be 3” at least 18” before it exits the roof but I don’t think it’s necessary. The only worry with that is if you live in an extremely cold area.  Good luck!

Comment: "I don't think meeting code is necessary" does not make for a compelling answer.